# Problema a ejecutar script mediante daemon [sytemd] que usa ficheros de su propio directorio

Tags: python, linux, bash

Pues tengo un daemon en systemd que arranca un script de python en un directorio, pongamos /home/user/proyecto/xxx.py

en dicho directorio hay tmb un archivo .txt que lee "xxx.py", de esta forma `open("y.txt")`
el caso es que si arranco dicho daemon, obtengo un error, tal que:
`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'y.txt'`

No seria para mi ideal editar el archivo y poner `open("/home/user/proyecto/y.txt")`

alguna otra solucion? o motivo?, gracias

Comment: aquí hay un uso del path realpath y getcwd https://stackoverflow.com/a/4060259/1423096

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir el archivo en python, utiliza la ruta completa:

```
with open('/home/user/proyecto/xxx.py', 'r') as archivo:
    ...
```

Tengo la sospecha de que se trata de la ruta, que tendría que ser absoluta. En caso de ser así, quizás es porque el script de inicio ha de tener su propio `CWD` (current work directory) y dentro de esa dirección no ha de encontrar el nombre del archivo que le pasas (que asumes relativo a cómo lo corres usualmente).

Comment: creo todo este problema vino a raiz de que cree un nuevo user , con permisos root y dicho directorio se encuentra en /home/nuevo_user , y he tenido problemas para acceder localmente a los propios archivos es decir tengo que recurrir a usar una rauta completa, a diferencia de con mi user original y principal, lo crree usando ```useradd nuevouser``` y luego le di permisos con ```visudo```

Comment: Cambiale los permisos a ese archivo para que lo puedas leer: `chmod o+r /home/user/proyecto/xxx.py`

Comment: Espero te hayan sido de ayuda mis respuestas.